# How to transform my animation into legacy?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, legacy

I have an issue with this[image]
I would like to be able to put legacy.

Thx for your reply.

I tried to use debug but the animation inspector is greyed.

Answer (score 0):

Select Your Boxing Object in assets and In Inspector choose Rig -> instead of Generic or Humanoid use Legacy. Did you try this? and still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I think it s good now thx